# MVC matching ModelState keys to ViewModel collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, collections, modelstate

Is it possible to match a ViewModel property to the matching ModelState.Key value when the ViewModel is a (has a) collection?

Example: To edit a collection of viewmodel items, I am using the [extension found here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

That adds a GUID to the id of the fields on the page.

example:

```
class Pets
{
    string animal;
    string name;
}
```

For a list of Pets, the generated html source is like this:

```
<input name="Pets.index" autocomplete="off" value="3905b306-a9..." type="hidden">
<input value="CAT" id="Pets_3905b306-a9...__animal" name="Pets[3905b306-a9...].animal" type="hidden">
<input value="MR. PEPPERS" id="Pets_3905b306-a9...__name" name="Pets[3905b306-a9...].name" type="hidden">


<input name="Pets.index" autocomplete="off" value="23342306-b4..." type="hidden">
<input value="DOG" id="Pets_23342306-b4...__animal" name="Pets[23342306-b4...].animal" type="hidden">
<input value="BRUTICUS" id="Pets_23342306-b4...__name" name="Pets[23342306-b4...].name" type="hidden">
```

So when this gets bound on post, the ModelState gets loaded with all the form fields.
In ModelSTate.Keys, there is:

```
Pets[23342306-b4...].name
Pets[23342306-b4...].animal
Pets[3905b306-a9...].name
Pets[3905b306-a9...].animal
```

Everything good so far, but I am doing some business logic validation, things like, cant add new animal if one exists with the same name. In that case, I want to be able to highlight the input field  that is in error.

So if my create function fails, it will return an error/key value pair like this:

```
{ error = "Duplicate Name", key="name" }
```

So I at least will now what property caused the problem.

But since my repository functions don't know about the view field ids, how can I match the key "name" to the appropriate ModelState key (in this case, either Pets[23342306-b4...].name or Pets[3905b306-a9...].name)?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the built in functionality of MVC for displaying collections (`Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pets)` or `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pets)`) with appropriate display/editor template, MVC would render something like this:

```
Pets[0].name
Pets[0].animal
Pets[1].name
Pets[1].animal
```

This maps to `IEnumerable<Pets>` and you know that first item has index of 0, second item 1 etc.

So if the second item has an error, you can set error for the `ModelState` key `"Pets[1].name"` for example.

Comment: The reason I use the other helper method to use a GUID is that this is for inline editing and the user can remove rows, so the order can change. They can also add rows, so a GUID is used to make sure the newly added row (coming from an ajax call) has a unique id.

Comment: As well, the ModelState not only has the list of items, but other field. It is not safe to just count the position in the list because the model can always be updated with more fields, which will break that mapping.

Comment: Yeah, we faced similar problem when we were making a MVC grid for our application. Instead of actually deleting rows, we had to mark them as deleted using a hidden field, and when we added a new row, we had to parse the index from the previous row and replace names and ids using jquery.

Comment: As for your other comment, adding more properties to your model wont break the mapping. You are only interested in what position each item of `Pets` collection has in that collection, not in `ModelState`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Html.BeginCollectionItem extension method, like I was, I was able to get around this by not using the GUID.  I need the dynamic add and delete, but I was always looking up known items, persons that have an ID, which I had in my editor.  So instead of using the GUID, I just assign the ID (uniqueId) in the code below.   I could then find the key because I knew it was Person[234232].  Of course if you are adding new items and not displaying selected items, it might not work for you.

```
        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName, string uniqueId)
    {
        var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
        string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : uniqueId;

        // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
        html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

        return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
    }
```